# Is auxiliary flag set when a number is stored?

Tags: assembly, x86, flags, x86-16, mov

Wikipedia says :

`Auxiliary flag is set(AF=1) if there is a carry from low nibble to high nibble or a borrow from a high nibble to low nibble of the low order 8-bit of a 16-bit number.(for example, in BCD addition or subtraction.)`

Does this mean that when I do :
`MOV AL, 25F`

since 25F is 00100101 and the lower nibble wasn't sufficient, AF gets set?

Or is it only during addition/subtraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mov`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/mov.html) does not affect any flags.

[`add`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/add.html) and [`sub`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/sub.html) do set `AF`, but so do many other instructions too, for example [`adc`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/adc.html), [`cmp`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/cmp.html), [`cmpxchg`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/cmpxchg.html), [`dec`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/dec.html), [`inc`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/inc.html), [`sbb`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/sbb.html), [`neg`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/neg.html).

Many other instructions leave `AF` in an undefined state, for example [`mul`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/mul.html), [`imul`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/imul.html), [`div`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/div.html), [`idiv`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/idiv.html), [`test`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/test.html), [`and`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/and.html), [`or`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/or.html), [`xor`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/xor.html), [`shr`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/shr.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could easily try it in the debugger instead of guessing. Or you could check [the reference](http://siyobik.info.gf/main/reference/instruction/MOV), which clearly says:

> Flags Affected: None.

Comment: thanks. so when is it affected? addition/multiplication related instructions?

Comment: @learner You will find a special table in either the AMD's or Intel's CPU manuals listing instructions and their effects on flags (set, reset, unchanged, modified, undefined).